# Replace an item <li> in a static list <ul> by a dragged item <li> coming from a sortable list <ul>

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, replace, jquery-ui-sortable

I am struggling with the drag and drop functionality of jQuery in combination with jQuery UI sortable. I want to replace an item ( li tag) in a HTML list with another item (also a li tag) dragged on it.

**So on the item, not on the list!!** It must be placed on a particular place and not being added at the end of the list. **I do not want to append it.**

The item I drag is coming from another list which is a sortable. (I do not know this matters or not.)

This is the code I have:

HTML:

```
<div id="source" class="listBlock">            
    <ul class="Sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default" id="item1">Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default" id="item2">Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default" id="item3">Item 3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default" id="item4">Item 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>                            

<div id="target" class="listBlock">            
    <ul class="DropTrue">
        <li class="ui-state-default slot" id="slot1">SLOT 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default slot" id="slot2">SLOT 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default slot" id="slot3">SLOT 3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default slot" id="slot4">SLOT 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The Javascript (using jQuery 1.7.2 and jQuery UI 1.8.18):

```
$(function() {
        $("ul.Sortable").sortable({
            connectWith: 'ul',
            opacity: 0.6,
        });
    });
```

Can you help me out, preferably with some example code? Much appreciated.

[edit 3 december 2014]

A complete working implementation:

```
var maxFieldLength = 30;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".detailsBlock").find("tbody").show();
    $(".showDetails").addClass("active");

    InitializeHeaderMap();

    $('#ResetButton').click(function () {
    $('span.headerText img').each(function (index) {
        $(this).click();
    });
    });

    $("ul.SourceList li").draggable({
    opacity: 0.6,
    revert: true
    });

    $("ul.TargetList li").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        PlaceInSlot(ui.draggable, $(this));
    }
    });
});

function OnNextClick() {
    CreateHeaderMap();
    return true;
}

function OnPreviousClick() {
    CreateHeaderMap();
    return true;
}

function InitializeHeaderMap() {
    var map = [];
    var headerMap = $('input[name=HeaderMap]').val();

    if ((headerMap !== null) && (headerMap !== undefined) && (headerMap.length > 0)) {
    try {
        map = JSON.parse(headerMap);
    } catch (err) {
        map = '';
    }
    }

    $.each(map, function (key, mapObject) {
    if (mapObject.HeaderIndex != -1) {
        var header = $("ul.SourceList li:icontains(" + mapObject.Header + ")");
        // Only place in slot when the header text is found
        if (header.text().length > 0) {
        var slot = $("ul.TargetList li[id=" + mapObject.Item + "]");
        PlaceInSlot(header, slot);
        }

    }
    });
}

function CreateHeaderMap() {

    var map = [];

    $("li.item").each(function () {

    var obj = {};
    obj['Item'] = $(this).attr('id');
    var position = $(this).find('span.headerText input').val();
    if ((position === 'undefined') || (position === null)) {
        position = -1;
    }
    obj['HeaderIndex'] = position;
    if (position !== 'undefined') {
        obj['Header'] = $(this).children('span.headerText').text().trim();
    } else {
        obj['Header'] = '';
    }

    map.push(obj);
    });

    $('input[name=HeaderMap]').val(JSON.stringify(map));
}

function PlaceInSlot(element, slot) {
    $(slot).children("span.slotText").hide();

    var revertImg = '<img name="image" src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/z4cehkuhv2mj502/Prullie_1_12.png" width="12" height="12" />';

    $(slot).children("span.headerText").html($(element).html()).append(revertImg);

    $(slot).parent().addClass("ui-state-default");

    $(slot).removeClass("validation-error");

    $(slot).droppable({
    disabled: true
    });

    var importRowFile = $(element).val();

    $(slot).attr("value", importRowFile);

    $(element).hide();

    $(slot).find("span.headerText img").click(function () {
    $(element).show();

    $(slot).children("span.slotText").show();
    $(slot).children("span.headerText").html('');
    $(slot).addClass("slot");
    $(slot).droppable({
        disabled: false
    });
    $(slot).off('click');
    });
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RWCH/9DPCW/

Answer (score 0):

I believe one could make each of the individual items "droppable", by their class name, e.g. "ui-item-droppable" and then on the drop event you can perform the swap then.

The JQuery example has it so the containing item is the droppable container, but there is no reason why you can't change that to be all the contained items.

You won't have any performance hit because you are only stating that the class is droppable, not each and every item in the target container.